# How to remove unwanted character from end of string?

Tags: php

In some cases when I use substr() function, it returns this char � at the end of returned string.

```
  $descrSh=substr($str,0,250);
```

How to solve this problem ???

Comment: sounds like an encoding issue to me

Comment: Your substr cuts an multi-byte char in half! Use `mb_substr($str,0,250, 'utf-8')` instead.

Comment: What is `$str` ? give us some examples.

Comment: yes it resolved this problem. thanks

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substr cuts an multi-byte char in half! Use mb_substr() instead.

```
mb_substr($str,0,250, 'utf-8')
```